# ActsAsSolr::SearchResults

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ROR application using acts_as_solr plugin as a search engine which runs on top of Lucene library.

now, i am able to search the results as below in controller

def search 
        @user_class=User.find_by_solr("rajesh")
       respond_to do |format|
       format.html # search.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml =>  @user_class }
    end

my question is how can i display the search results in search.html.erb page

presently doing as below

but getting error as

undefined method `each' for ActsAsSolr::SearchResults:0x463c2e4

Help me , Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

Your `@user_class` object is not an array, but an instance of the class `ActsAsSolr::SearchResults`. To access the resulting documents, call its `docs` method:

```
<% for user_class in @user_class.docs %>
  <%= user_class.name %>
<% end %>
```

Your `@user_class` object also contains other useful information like:

```
@user_class.total     # total number of results
@user_class.max_score # highest score of any result
```

See `lib/search_results.rb` in the acts_as_solr source code for all the available methods.